# 64-bit Xorshift with 2^96 or 2^128 period

Tags: pseudo-random-generators

Can we create Xorshift generator, as Marsaglia in "Xorshift RNGs" does, using 64-bit numbers, but with period 2^96 or 2^128?

He proposed PRNG with period 2^96:

```
t=(xˆ(x<<3))ˆ(yˆ(y>>19))ˆ(zˆ(z<<6));x=y;y=z;return(z=t);
```

But this works on 32-bit ints, as I think. I can't generalize his work to create similar thing working on 64-bit numbers, but I think it could be possible. He created it probably using matrices in 3.1 and precomputed triples in 3. But I'm still not sure how to do it.

Quality of such PRNG doesn't matter. It just have to has period guaranteed.

Comment: Point of order, this PRNG has period $2^{96}-1$. It can't be $2^{96}$ because $x=y=z=0$ is a fixed point. All LSFR generators (which are a proper superset of xorshift) have this property.

Comment: @Pseudonym you're right, I missed minus 1.

Comment: @Tom The Wikipedia [article on Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) mentions xorshift+ generators due to Vigna, and shows an example PRNG of this kind with two `uint64_t` as state and a claimed period of $2^{128}-1$ is shown. Have you had a look at Vigna's work for the principles of construction for xorshift+ PRNGs?

Comment: @njuffa I looked at Vigna's PRNGs (mostly xoroshiro, with rotations, not xorshfits) but I don't understand them enough to make my own xorshift. But it looks like I misssed xorshift128p, which is in fact xorshift with 2^128-1 and two 64-bit states. This could close my problem.

Comment: I you really don't care about quality, simply implement a 96 or 128 bits counter by propagating a carry from the low order word to the high order one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the period and not about randomness, use a 96-bit or 128-bit counter.

If you care about randomness, use any decent PRNG.  It doesn't matter which you pick.

If you don't want it to repeat in your lifetime, a random 128-bit value from a decent PRNG is incredibly unlikely to ever repeat within your lifetime.

Comment: I can't implement 96-bit or 128-bit counter on 64-bit ints. It can be done but function needed is to slow for my purpose. I was hoping that maybe somehow simple 96-bit xorshift would be faster than 128-bit counter on 64-bit registers. But I don't really need nothing more qualitative than counter. I was thinking also about some simplification of add-with-carry generator (64-bit state, 2^128 period), but it also doesn't seem to be efficient enough and needs big state. In both cases 128-bit counter is more efficient, even implemented on 64-bit ints. Maybe couner is unbetlable.

Comment: @Tom, if you want to know how to implement a 96-bit or 128-bit counter, or a non-repeating sequence of 96- or 128-bit values, I suggest you ask a new question about that.  That's much easier to implement than to necessarily do it based on xorshift, and there are many options.  Right now this seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).

Comment: Paradoxically, a number generator that repeats extremely rarely is very non random !

Comment: @D.W. ok, maybe I will try.

Comment: @YvesDaoust They aren't random, but thankfully they usually aren't rare. Exercise (very hard): Consider a linear-shift feedback PRNG with $k$ bits constructed in the following way: Shift the entire $k$-bit word left by one bit, and set bit 0 to be XOR of some combination of bits from the original word. Show that there are $\frac{2^k}{k} - O(2^{k/2})$ such combinations that will give you a period of $2^k-1$.

Comment: @Pseudonym: did I ever say that they were rare ? Of course not, they are designed to have a long period ! But this has nothing to do with my comment.

Comment: Of course, Just adding more information and a fun challenge.

Comment: “Too slow”: Twenty or more years ago IBM published a linear congruential random number generator that runs in one number per cycle, using floating point arithmetic and fused multiply-add and calculating several random numbers in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I cracked this problem a little bit. In fact, not using xorshift, bit using LFSR. As I wrote in the comments I want to use it as an alternative to the counter. LFSRs are in fact used as a counters, beacuse have simpler feedback logic than natural binary counters or Gray-code counters, and therefore can operate at higher clock rates.

We can consider something as simply as that for 64-bit counter:

```
uint64_t lfsr = 123;
lfsr = -(lfsr & 1) & 0x800000000000000D ^ (lfsr >>= 1);
```

Now we can aplly it using only 32-bit ints:

```
uint64_t result = 0;

uint32_t lfsr_low = 123;
uint32_t lfsr_hi = 0;
unsigned tmp = 0;

tmp = lfsr_low & 1;
lfsr_low = -tmp & 13 ^ (lfsr_low = ((lfsr_hi & 1) << 31) | (lfsr_low >> 1));
lfsr_hi = -tmp & 0x80000000 ^ (lfsr_hi >>= 1);

result = ((uint64_t)lfsr_hi << 32) | lfsr_low;
```

We can do the same with 128-bit LFSR on 64-bit ints. Anyway, it would be faster to use just two different 64-bit LFSRs to get period 2^128, for example:

```
lfsr_1 = -(lfsr_1 & 1) & 0x800000000000000D ^ (lfsr_1 >>= 1);
lfsr_2 = -(lfsr_2 & 1) & 0x800000000000000E ^ (lfsr_2 >>= 1);
lfsr_2 += lfsr_1;
```

It is still slower in my tests than counter, even 128-bit counter implemented on 64-bit ints, but it works. lfsr_2 could have period 2^128-2^65+1. This is because adding or xoring two PRNG generators with period p_1 and p_2 should give a generator with period p_1*p_2. Until their bits are not correlated in such a way, they will cancel out each other. For 4-bit LFSRs:

```
lfsr_1 = -(lfsr_1 & 1) & 9 ^ (lfsr_1 >>= 1);
lfsr_2 = -(lfsr_2 & 1) & 12 ^ (lfsr_2 >>= 1);
lfsr_2 += lfsr_1;
```

I got period not equal to 2^8-2^5+1, but 210. So there is some risk of pathological behavior, and perhaps even falling such a system in a very short cycle. It's hard to estimate.

Comment: "it would be faster to use just two different 64-bit LFSRs to get period 2^128" ...as long as one of the LSFRs is only bumped every 2^64 cycles of the other. If you have two synchronised PRNGs with period 2^64, and you xor the outputs together, you get a (probably better) PRNG with period 2^64.

Comment: @Pseudonym you're right. I will change my post. Adding or xoring two PRNG generators with period p_1 and p_2 should give a generator with period p_1*p_2. Until their bits are not correlated in such a way, they will cancel out each other.

Comment: In general, combining two synchronised PRNG generators with period $p_1$ and $p_2$ should give a PRNG with period $\mathrm{lcm}(p_1,p_2)$.

Comment: @Pseudonym it depends also on how we combine them. We can multiply xor, add or something else. It is best to use an operation that will be across (write informally) the linearity that generators can exhibit. If LFSRs work in GF(2) I would not use xor which is linear in GF(2). But the additon is better idea (it is not linear in GF(2)). And indeed if we do lfsr_2 ^= lfsr_1; we will get period 15 in my toy example (this is lcm). But addition gives much bigger period. Of course with much stronger, independent from each other PRNGs we don't have to worry about that so much, here we have to.